# String.charAt() vs String.at()

Tags: javascript, charat

What is the difference between the "String.charAt()" method and the "String.at()" method?

I tried to understand how they work, but other than the fact that the "at" method can have a negative value, I did not find any more.

Comment: Link to the pair of documentation URLs you’re relying on, please.

Comment: The fact that `.at()` understands a negative index is the only difference.

Comment: Did you look up the docs for the two functions? What did it tell you?

Comment: `charAt` has also been supported far longer.

Comment: @Pointy plus the part where `.at()` also works for arrays, giving you one function for doing "the same thing" to both arrays and strings (which already supported array notation for accessing letters the same way you would array elements).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OK sure, that's a thing, but this question isn't taking that into account I don't think. Still it's a very good point.

Answer (score 8):

`at()` is a newer addition to JavaScript compared to `charAt()`. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at#comparing_methods), both `charAt()` and `at()` are valid, but `at()` is more "succinct and readable". The ability to use negative indexes makes your code more concise since you can do things like `myString.at(-2)` instead of `myString.charAt(myString.length - 2)`.

`charAt()` has better support of older browser versions ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt#browser_compatibility), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at#browser_compatibility)), but I would give that absolutely no consideration, unless you have an extremely specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

**at()**

- is newer (supported by all browsers only since March 2022)
- works with any iterable object
- accepts negative values as arguments

**charAt()**

- is older and as such supported by older browser versions
- only works with strings
- doesn't accept negative values as arguments